# lists in vue gives should have explicit keys error

Tags: vue.js, v-for, quasar

I was following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iml3hDVboHk&t=359s
However, on the code

I get this error,
component lists rendered with v-for should have explicit keys.

How do I fix it?

Comment: could you add your source code

Comment: I fixed it. I had forgotten to add the return parameter. Anyways, thank you!

Comment: You need to specify a unique key for elements rendered with v-for. See the documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Answer (score 0):

In Vue.js, all elements that are rendered through v-for must have a unique key property.